# Something went wrong while saving the customer?

Tags: magento2, customer-account

When I edit a customer from admin or front-end then showing the below error

**Something went wrong while saving the customer**

When I Print Error -- >

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE `customer_entity` SET `website_id` = ?, `email` = ?, `group_id` = ?, `store_id` = ?, `created_at` = '2019-03-14 12:57:34', `updated_at` = '2019-06-29 11:25:45', `disable_auto_group_change` = ?, `created_in` = ?, `prefix` = ?, `firstname` = ?, `middlename` = ?, `lastname` = ?, `suffix` = ?, `password_hash` = ?, `rp_token` = ?, `rp_token_created_at` = ?, `default_billing` = ?, `default_shipping` = ?, `taxvat` = ?, `confirmation` = ?, `gender` = ?, `failures_num` = ?, `first_failure` = ?, `lock_expires` = ? WHERE (`entity_id`=104903)

Comment: Which Magento 2 version are you using?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.2.6

Comment: Above issue not for all customer just for few customer

Comment: I think your mysql proccess went to idle. You need to login in mysql using ssh and fire below commands:
show PROCESSLIST;
killl process_id [which you find idle state]

Comment: Thanks!! DONE already but not get success

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im

Comment: I'm having a similar issue: how did you print the error? and did you solve it?